# What do you call it when a group of neglected people spontaneously forms a cruel society?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to come up with a word to describe what happens in cartoons (and probably real life) when a traumatic event leads to a group of ordinary people (usually children) to fend for themselves. They then form a new society resembling a dictatorship ruled by bullies.

Comment: If you exclude the "traumatic event" part, then "anarchy."

Comment: "Anarchy" is perfect, thanks! Post that as an answer for +25 from me!

Comment: I [went with it](http://blog.wassupy.com/2011/02/kids-castle.html), thanks @advs89: "...the others would just sit and read magazines while the kids they were supposed to be watching fell into *anarchy* ruled by sugar-crazed, toy hoarding bullies"

Comment: Just to be pedantic, it's not anarchy because there *is* structure, and the rudiments of self-governance. If in the future you need a less casual word for it, I'd try *dictatorship* or *ochlocracy*.

Comment: I wonder if there are shades of gray with the "disorder" and "unstructured" parts of *anarchy*. It seems like there can be even a little order or structure, and still exhibit traits characteristic to an anarchy, like confusion, chaos, and (albeit some) much less order than a the previous situation, or the ideal situation.

Comment: @Michael, very nice your letter to The Kid's Castle. I am wondering, where is the "traumatic event that leads a group of [...] children to fend themselves [...] then form a new society"?

Comment: @Jon Purdy:  From the sentence above it sounds more like anarchy than a dictatorship.  Granted, "ruled [by sugar-crazed...]" was probably not the best word to follow "anarchy" since "anarchy" essentially means that there is no ruler.  However, my understanding of the word anarchy is that there is no _official and structured_ governing body.  "Gangs," if you will, are still allowed under the definition of "anarchy."  (or so I believe)

Comment: Hm. "Bullyarchy"?

Comment: I think that's called "High School"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you exclude the "traumatic event" part, then "anarchy" works.

from dictionary.com,

> 4 :  confusion; chaos; disorder: Intellectual and moral anarchy
>   followed his loss of faith.

Comment: It's about time you made this an answer. +1

Comment: haha, sorry about that

Answer (score 7):

I'd call it a "*Lord of the Flies* situation". *Lord of the Flies* is a novel about some school kids on a field trip that are shipwrecked and wash up on an island with no adults, and form just what you described: a spontaneous, cruel society of neglected people.

I think nearly all somewhat-educated adult English speakers would understand exactly what you're talking about; we all had to read it in high school.

Answer (score 0):

I would call this *social atavism* in general.  The term for the form of government involved (rule by those best at causing fear, pain, injury and death) is *despotism*.